# what‘s the best regex for the multiple text?

Tags: python, regex, file

The file content is below:

```
#encoding=utf8
__author__ = "naci"
__title__ = "test script"
__desc__ = "test description" 
or __desc__ = """
    test description.
"""
# start your script here
```

question:
     what's the best regex for get author, title, and desc? the "" maybe '' or """""" maybe''''''

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: Have you tried anything? You should also provide us, in addition to your research effort, the expected output. You can visit [ask] if you need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [***re.findall()***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) function:

```
import re

s = '''
#encoding=utf8
__author__ = "naci"
__title__ = "test script"
__desc__ = "test description"
or __desc__ = """
    test description.
"""
'''

data = re.findall(r'__(?P<attr>\w+)_ = (?P<val>"[^"]+"|"""[^"]+""")', s)
print(data)
```

The output(pairs: *key/value*):

```
[('author_', '"naci"'), ('title_', '"test script"'), ('desc_', '"test description"'), ('desc_', '"""\n    test description.\n"""')]
```